# how to make bootstrap carousel touch slide?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

how  do you make bootstrap carousel touch slide ?

Is there a way ? to tweak that code  to enable fingers to swap the slides?

Here is the [carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/#myCarousel)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Download jQuery & jQuery mobile libraries from http://jquery.com/ and http://jquerymobile.com/

Include the jQuery mobile library in your site

The jQuery mobile library gives you touch support. You can add the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   $("#bsCarousel").swiperight(function() {  
      $("#bsCarousel").carousel('prev');  
    });  
   $("#bsCarousel").swipeleft(function() {  
      $("#bsCarousel").carousel('next');  
   });  
});
```

Comment: Alternately, Jacob Thornton at one point recommended using http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/ for this.

Comment: For someone looking for an updated solution, the carousel now supports touch by default (current version is v5.3 as of today). If you'd like to disable touch then see this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/carousel/#disable-touch-swiping.

Answer (score -1):

For all use class :

Use Hammer.js

https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js

and jquery.hammer.js

https://github.com/hammerjs/jquery.hammer.js

```
$('.carousel').hammer().bind('swipeleft', function (event)   {
   $(event.target).carousel('next');
});

$('.carousel').hammer().bind('swiperight', function (event) {
   $(event.target).carousel('prev');
});
```

Comment: Include hammer.js and jquery.hammer.js library in your site